# Address Labels Printing

Tags: address-labels

I have no problem printing my contact group mailing labels, however is it possible

to only print a full sheet of mailing labels for a single contact?

Any assistance appreciated.

Comment: If it's only one or two contacts you need to do this for, I'd just do it in MS Word or LibreOffice which both have features for mailing labels and you can fill a sheet with the same address.

Comment: if you are using Drupal I would build a view with a grid and get it set up to print a whole sheet of same details maybe

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SE! There isn't a built in way to print multiple labels for a single contact within the label printing functionality. Demerit's suggestion above is probably what I'd do, but if you have a regular need and want to do it entirely within CiviCRM you could produce a message template with multiple copies of the same address on it and then use the print/Merge Document on the single contact. You would have to be careful how empty address fields were handled to make sure it looked right and the spacing didn't change, but some smarty should be able to do this.